# Adding text line in Equation Environment

Tags: equations

I am a new user in LaTex.
1. Can someone please help me what wrong is with this code.

```
\begin{equation*}
T_{Loop Filter}(s)=K_{p}+\frac{K_{i}}{s}\\
The overall transfer function of given PLL can be given as\\
\frac{{\phi}_{c}(s)}{{\phi}(s)}=\frac{T_{Loop Filter}(s)*\frac{1}{s}}{1+\frac{T_{Loop Filter}(s)*\frac{1}{s}}\\
\frac{\phi_{c}(s)}{\phi(s)}=\frac{K_{p}(s)+K_{i}}{s^{2}+K_{p}(s)+K_{i}}\\
In general transfer function for a second order closed loop control system is given as\\
T_{second order}=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}{\omega}s}{s_{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}s+{\omega}^{2}}\\
On comparing {\omega}={sqrt{K_i}}  {\delta}=\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}
\end{equation*}
```

I am getting following error

> "Runaway argument? {1+\frac {T_{Loop Filter}(s)*\frac {1}{s}}\ \frac {\phi _{c}(s)}{\phi \ETC. ! File ended while scanning use of
>   \frac

2. What is the professional  way to write equations for research paper(`\begin{equation}` or `\begin{eqnarray}` or `$$` or `\begin{OtherStyle}`
3. Can we add text line directly in inside \begin{equation} environment without any commands
4. How to use center aligned(Under `\begin{equation}`) as well as align with respect to particular character(`\begin{Align}`) in equation environment.

Comment: Don't use double dollar `$$ $$`. Use `\[ \]` instead. But if you wish you can use `equation` or `equation*` for unnumbered.

Comment: I suggest you to use `T_{\text{Loop Filter}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `equation` environment is for numbered one-lined formulae. Also any text inserted in an equation must be introduced  with `\text{…}` (command defined by the `amsmath` package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think flalign* and \intertext{} are very good for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
& & T_{Loop Filter}(s)&=K_{p}+\frac{K_{i}}{s} & & \\
\intertext{The overall transfer function of given PLL can be given as}
& & \frac{{\phi}_{c}(s)}{{\phi}(s)}&=\frac{T_{Loop Filter}(s)*\frac{1}{s}}{1+\frac{T_{Loop Filter}}(s)*\frac{1}{s}} & & \\
& & \frac{\phi_{c}(s)}{\phi(s)}&=\frac{K_{p}(s)+K_{i}}{s^{2}+K_{p}(s)+K_{i}} & & 
\intertext{In general transfer function for a second order closed loop control system is given as}
& & T_{second order}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}s}{s_{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}s+{\omega}^{2}} & & \\
& \rlap{\text{On comparing}} & {\omega}&={sqrt{K_i}}  {\delta}=\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}} & &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind interest. It solved my problem. I have further doubts.1. Can you please explain significance for position of '&' in \begin{flalign} environment. What will the effect if i will use single '&' both side 2. Why we are using \rlap{\text} ; Cant we use \intertext{} again.

Comment: You can see examples of using flalign in this website http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=4868

Answer (score 0):

You have a misssing `}` in your code.

This should work:

```
\[
T_{Loop Filter}(s)=K_{p}+\frac{K_{i}}{s}
\]
The overall transfer function of given PLL can be given as
\[
\frac{{\phi}_{c}(s)}{{\phi}(s)}=\frac{T_{Loop Filter}(s)*\frac{1}{s}}{1+\frac{T_{Loop Filter}}(s)*\frac{1}{s}}
\]
\[
\frac{\phi_{c}(s)}{\phi(s)}=\frac{K_{p}(s)+K_{i}}{s^{2}+K_{p}(s)+K_{i}}
\]
In general transfer function for a second order closed loop control system is given as
\[
T_{second order}=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}s}{s_{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}s+{\omega}^{2}}
\]
On comparing
\[ 
{\omega}={sqrt{K_i}}  {\delta}=\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}
\]
```

I don't try all `}` so some could be added.

Comment: erh, no, you cannot break lines in `equation*`

Comment: Right, I look only to missign `}` due to the error. I'll modify my answer to fit

Comment: Thanks it works fine. but cant we align these equation by some means with respect to any character viz. '=' without using \begin{align}.

Comment: You can use split in equation. See more detail in this website https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath

Answer (score 0):

Can i use $ Equation $ inside and outside \intertext{} under flalign{} environment .Because of these two lines my all equations got justified to left.Please help in this regard 
Before adding it is properly justified wrt center
**\begin{flalign*}
& & \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}*{s}}{s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}*{s}+{\omega}^{2}} & & \
\end{flalign*}**
After adding bellow text, instead of center it is justified toward left
**{\intertext{On comparing}} ${\omega}={\sqrt{K_i}}$ \quad ${\delta}=\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}$\**